# postfix - error sending email

Tags: postfix, msmtp

When I try to send an email using mutt (and msmtp) i get the following error:

```
msmtp: envelope from address qorg@vxempire.xyz not accepted by the server
msmtp: server message: 530 5.7.0 Must issue a STARTTLS command first
msmtp: could not send mail (account qorg2 from /home/qorg/.msmtprc)
```

This is my postconf -n:

```
alias_database = hash:/etc/aliases
alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases
append_dot_mydomain = no
biff = no
compatibility_level = 2
home_mailbox = Maildir/
inet_interfaces = all
inet_protocols = ipv4
mailbox_command = /usr/lib/dovecot/deliver
mailbox_size_limit = 0
milter_default_action = accept
milter_protocol = 6
mydestination = $myhostname, $mydomain, localhost.$mydomain, localhost
mydomain = vxempire.xyz
myhostname = vxempire.xyz
mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8, 192.168.1.0/24
myorigin = vxempire.xyz
non_smtpd_milters = inet:localhost:12301
readme_directory = no
recipient_delimiter = +
relayhost =
smtp_tls_loglevel = 1
smtp_tls_security_level = may
smtp_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtp_scache
smtpd_banner = $myhostname ESMTP
smtpd_milters = inet:localhost:12301
smtpd_recipient_restrictions = permit_mynetworks,permit_auth_destination,permit_sasl_authenticated,reject
smtpd_relay_restrictions = permit_mynetworks permit_sasl_authenticated defer_unauth_destination
smtpd_sasl_auth_enable = yes
smtpd_sasl_local_domain = $myhostname
smtpd_sasl_path = private/auth
smtpd_sasl_security_options = noanonymous, noplaintext
smtpd_sasl_tls_security_options = noanonymous
smtpd_sasl_type = dovecot
smtpd_tls_auth_only = yes
smtpd_tls_cert_file = /etc/letsencrypt/live/vxempire.xyz-0002/fullchain.pem
smtpd_tls_key_file = /etc/letsencrypt/live/vxempire.xyz-0002/privkey.pem
smtpd_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtpd_scache
smtpd_use_tls = yes
```

Is there something wrong with it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This wasnt a postfix problem. This was a msmtp problem. I wasn't "forcing" the tls connection. I fixed it with the following in ~/.msmtprc:

```
auth           on
tls            on
tls_trust_file /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt
logfile        ~/.msmtp.log
```